# DBeaver error resolving maven dependencies

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc, dbeaver

I am trying to connect to a remote MySQL database using DBeaver 3.6.3.
But when I try to add the server as a new connection, I need to select a connection type. I select MySQL and as soon as I click on next, it gives me this error

[image: Imgur]

I have tried restoring driver settings to default - no effect.
I have tried removing the metadata folder in Users and restarting - no effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to reinstall the driver? 
I've tried DBeaver on Linux, mysql connector v 5.1.39 worked fine (mysql 5.6.15).

I had issues a month ago with dbeaver and connecting to a mssql db, updating dbeaver to the v4.0.0 fixed it, maybe you could try that too?
You'll have to build it though, if this doesn't scare you: https://github.com/serge-rider/dbeaver

Comment: I'm afraid that wont be a solution, i'm working on a pc at work and we have restricted permissions, aka i dont have admin rights and i cant install things on here, i downloaded dbeaver via a local software center application

Comment: that wont be an option because as i said i cannot install things on my work laptop

Comment: You can get a portable version of mysql workbench, no need to install.

Comment: oh, cool I did not know that. using workbench i was able to connect. thank you

Answer (score 37):

In my case I had to add the Maven index site url in DBeaver as follows:

1. Go to DbBeaver "Preferences" menu
2. Locate "Connections" -> "Drivers" -> "Maven"
3. Click "Add" and paste this link: https://mvnrepository.com
4. Click "Apply" and "Close"
5. On the driver settings menu that will appear, click "Download"

After the download has finished, I was able to connect to the database.

Comment: mvnrepository.com is not a repository, it is an index site.

Comment: @manudicri Mark's comment was mainly about the terminology and not the actual steps of the answer. I integrated his correction by editing the 1st line of my answer.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible that you don't have direct internet access on your working plan (e.g. because of some corporate proxy).
In this case you could try:

Download drivers manually from https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html and then add jars in driver editor
Try to configure HTTP proxy in preferences

Note: Ref site

https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/1898

Comment: Link seems changed. Try: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/

Answer (score 4):

I fixed maven dependencies error encountered while installing db driver as follow:

- first set up `http_proxy` if needed
- then add the [mvn URL repository](https://mvnrepository.com/) in the download configuration settings as describe in [this issue](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/3780#issuecomment-1049615593)

*Solution tested on DBeaver Version 21.3.5*

Answer (score 1):

if any body is facing the above issue then remove the jar files from dbvear library  and add the below jar file download from the link below and add it in the driver library and try to connect it.it worked for me hope this might helpful

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/8.2.0.jre8/source-code